# .Net Winforms DataGridView DataBinding

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I support a winforms application that is used by a financial planning team.  One of the main screens of the program, referred to as the Planning Grid, uses a datagridview to show changes in the financial plan, week over week, for product groups that the company sells.

The datagridview displays financial measures, by week, for selected product groups.  There is one column for each week of the year (total of 52 columns).
There are 15 financial measures per product group, so performing a product group selection in the UI adds 15 sequential rows of data to the datagridview.

Currently, the program gets the data back from the business layer in a 2 dimensional array.  It then builds the rows programatically by looping through the array and using each row of the array to create a row in the data grid.

My question relates to data binding.  I would like to refactor the code to use data binding to automatically build the data grid.  Essentially, I want to return a list of business objects (PlannedProductGroup) and set that list as the data source for the datagridview.  My problem however, is that I don't know how to handle the binding.  When I have done datagridview binding in the past each object in the data source equates to one row in the grid.  This time however, one object would be creating 15 rows in the grid, and I am not sure if this is possible using data binding.

Is what I want to do possible?  If so, does anyone know how to implement this more complex data binding scenario?

Edit - Adding Snippets of current implementation that I want to refactor

```
        'create rows
        Dim _planningDetailsArray(,) As Single = Load_Planning_Details()
        For Each productGroup As ProductGroup In _productGroups
            If Product_Group_Checked(productGroup.ID) Then

                'Measure.ProductGroupId
                productGroupId = Convert.ToInt32(_planningDetailsArray((productGroupCounter * Measure.Count) + Measure.ProductGroupId, 0))
                productGroupName = _productGroups.Find(Function(p) p.ID = productGroupId).Name
                myDataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewIntegerCell(productGroupId))
                For weekCounter As Integer = 0 To 51
                    Dim priceMultipleId As Integer = CInt(_planningDetailsArray((productGroupCounter * Measure.Count) + Measure.PriceMultiple, weekCounter))
                    Dim priceMultipleName As String = _priceMultiples.Find(Function(p) p.ID = priceMultipleId).Name
                    Dim complexOffer = String.Empty
                    If CInt(_planningDetailsArray((productGroupCounter * Measure.Count) + Measure.Complex, weekCounter)) = 1 Then
                        complexOffer = " *"
                    End If
                    Dim retailPrice As String = Math.Abs(_planningDetailsArray((productGroupCounter * Measure.Count) + Measure.RetailPrice, weekCounter)).ToString("C2") & complexOffer
                    Dim cellText = $"{priceMultipleName} {retailPrice}"
                    _myDataGridViewCell = NewDataGridViewTextCell(cellText)
                    If _blackoutCollection.Contains((weekCounter + 1).ToString) Then
                        _myDataGridViewCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray
                    Else
                        _myDataGridViewCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGray
                    End If
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(_myDataGridViewCell)
                Next
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewIntegerCell(Measure.ProductGroupId))
                myDataGridViewRow.HeaderCell.Value = productGroupName
                myDataGridViewRow.ReadOnly = True
                _dgvPlanningDetails.Rows.Add(myDataGridViewRow)

                'Measure.Retail_Price
                myDataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewIntegerCell(productGroupId))
                For weekCounter As Integer = 0 To 51
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewSingleCellDash(_planningDetailsArray((productGroupCounter * Measure.Count) + Measure.RetailPrice, weekCounter), False, True))
                Next
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewIntegerCell(Measure.RetailPrice))
                myDataGridViewRow.HeaderCell.Value = "   Retail Price"
                myDataGridViewRow.Visible = ToolStripCheckBox_Retail.Checked
                myDataGridViewRow.ReadOnly = _isReadOnly
                myDataGridViewRow.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
                _dgvPlanningDetails.Rows.Add(myDataGridViewRow)

                'Measure.Price_Multiple_ID
                myDataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewIntegerCell(productGroupId))
                For weekCounter As Integer = 0 To 51
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewComboBoxCell(_priceMultiples.AsEnumerable(), Convert.ToInt32(_planningDetailsArray((productGroupCounter * Measure.Count) + Measure.PriceMultiple, weekCounter))))
                Next
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells.Add(NewDataGridViewIntegerCell(Measure.PriceMultiple))
                myDataGridViewRow.HeaderCell.Value = "   Price Multiple"
                myDataGridViewRow.Visible = ToolStripCheckBox_Retail.Checked
                myDataGridViewRow.ReadOnly = _isReadOnly
                _dgvPlanningDetails.Rows.Add(myDataGridViewRow)            
            End If
        Next
```

Edit 2 - Adding POC code
I created a quick Proof of Concept project to show what I want to do.  Each person object should be two rows in the data grid, one row for the FavoriteColors list and one row for the FavoriteFoods list.

Public Class Form1

```
Public Sub New ()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim people = New List(Of Person)

    Dim person1 = New Person
    person1.Name = "Jim"
    person1.FavoriteColors = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Red", "Green", "Blue"})
    person1.FavoriteFoods = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Pizza", "Salad", "Burger"})

    Dim person2 = New Person
    person2.Name = "Bob"
    person2.FavoriteColors = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Yellow", "Black", "Pink"})
    person2.FavoriteFoods = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Hotdog", "French Fries", "Steak"})

    people.Add(person1)
    people.Add(person2)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = people
End Sub

Private Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property FavoriteColors As List(Of String)
    Public Property FavoriteFoods As List(Of  String)
End Class
```

End Class

Comment: Can you share the code of how you're currently populating the `DataGridView`?  Changing it to be data bound shouldn't be a "complex data binding scenario".

Comment: *This time however, one object would be creating 15 rows in the grid, and I am not sure if this is possible using data binding.*  → An object would be creating 15 rows? How?

Comment: @Zer0

There is ALOT of code to build the grid, but I can add some snippets to help you get an idea of how it currently works

Comment: That one object would have to have a BindingList<T> or DataTable property.

Comment: @RezaAghaei

I added a code snippet above.  For brevity, it does not show every row being generated, but as you can see in the example I added, the grid would show week by week changes to a product groups RetailPrice and PriceMultiple.  Other measures included in the grid would include invoice price, wholesale price, Cost of Goods sold, Gross Profit, etc

Comment: @LarsTech

Do you have an example code snippet or something to share that I could look at?  That appraoch is basically what I am looking for.  I was thinking I could have lists of values in my object such as RetailPrice, PriceMultiple, Gross Profit, etc that would contain the raw data.  My problem is figuring out how to bind one object containing multiple lists of values, and getting each list to be represented as a row in the data grid

Comment: @LarsTech

To elaborate, if my data source was a list with multiple PlannedProductGroup objects....If each PlannedProductGroup object had 15 lists in it exposed via Property, how would I implement binding so that one PlannedProductGroup object creates 15 rows in the grid, 1 for each list?

Comment: It's hard to "see" what your interface looks like.  As an example, you would have a DataGridView DataSource set to the List<T> property of your object.

Comment: @LarsTech  I added a second edit to the OP that includes code that will build and compile.  It shows a VERY simple example of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to picture what you describe. So, I will keep it simple and focus on the `Person` example.

Using a `List<T>` as a `DataSource` to a `DataGridView` will work. However, it will only display “publicly” exposed “Properties” that are NOT COLLECTIONS.

In the `Person` class example, the grid will only display the "name" column. And, this makes sense… the grid is not going to know how to make a single “Cells” value equal to a collection of values.

Therefore, if you want to display each item in the list as a “column” in the grid…. Then you will need to do this. I am not sure if binding or some other mechanism would help, however, I am confident it would not be difficult to create a method that given a `List<T>` would return a `DataTable` that is set up as you describe.

Given that there are TWO (2) list for each `Person` (I assume 15 in the original example), this implies there would be two rows for each `Person.` If this is correct, then about the only thing you would need to worry about is… HOW MANY COLUMNS are you going to need given a List of `Person` such that, each person “could” have a different number of items (Colors, Foods) in one of the lists.

It appears obvious that the number of columns you will need will be the items count from the largest (Colors, Foods) List of ALL `Person`s in the `people` list. I am guessing this is always going to be 52 in the original case, however, it would be prudent to check this as a crash is guaranteed otherwise.

To help, a method is needed to get the number of columns for the `DataTable`. This `GetMaxColumns` method takes a `List<Person>` and returns the count from the largest “Color” and “Food” lists. This will guarantee that we will stay inbounds regardless of the size of any color or food list. It may look like below…

```
Private Function GetMaxColumns(people As List(Of Person)) As Int32
    Dim max = 0
    For Each person In people
        If (person.FavoriteColors.Count > max) Then
            max = person.FavoriteColors.Count
        End If
        If (person.FavoriteFoods.Count > max) Then
            max = person.FavoriteFoods.Count
        End If
    Next
    Return max
End Function
```

Next a method `GetDataTable` takes a `List<Person>` and returns a `DataTable` with the proper number of columns for the given `List<Person>`. It is here where naming the columns may be convenient.

```
Private Function GetDataTable(people As List(Of Person)) As DataTable
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    Dim maxColumns = GetMaxColumns(people)
    For index = 0 To maxColumns
        dt.Columns.Add()
    Next
    Return dt
End Function
```

A `FillDataTable` method takes a `List<Person>` and a `DataTable` then fills the `DataTable` from the `List<Person>` as previously described. There will be two rows for each person, however, the second row under the name column will be empty since it will be the same name as the previous row.

In the code below, a loop begins through each `Person` in the list. The name is added to the row, then a loop through the “Color” list to add each color value. Then a second row is added which contains the values in the “Food” list. The name is not added to the second row.

```
Private Sub FillDataTable(people As List(Of Person), dt As DataTable)
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim curCol = 0
    For Each person In people
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        curCol = 0
        dr(curCol) = person.Name.ToString()
        curCol += 1
        For Each favColor In person.FavoriteColors
            dr(curCol) = favColor
            curCol += 1
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        curCol = 1
        For Each favFood In person.FavoriteFoods
            dr(curCol) = favFood
            curCol += 1
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
End Sub
```

Lastly, putting all this together may look something like below….

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim people = New List(Of Person)
    Dim person = New Person
    person.Name = "Jim"
    person.FavoriteColors = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Red", "Green", "Blue"})
    person.FavoriteFoods = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Pizza", "Salad", "Burger"})
    people.Add(person)

    person = New Person
    person.Name = "Bob"
    person.FavoriteColors = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Yellow", "Black", "Pink"})
    person.FavoriteFoods = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Hotdog", "French Fries", "Steak"})
    people.Add(person)

    person = New Person
    person.Name = "John"
    person.FavoriteColors = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Purple", "Olive Grey", "Polka Dot"})
    person.FavoriteFoods = New List(Of String)(New String() {"Ice Cream", "Fish", "Crutons"})
    people.Add(person)

    Dim GridTable = GetDataTable(people)
    FillDataTable(people, GridTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to set up your code examples in your response.  I dropped your functions into my proof of concept codebase and not only did it compile/build with no changes needed, it accomplished exactly what I was wanted to do.
I knew that data binding would display publicly exposed properties but I was unaware of the caveat that this does not consider collections.  That piece of information coupled with your example implementation set me on the right track.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the structure of your data in the database. For example, is the relation data stored in 52 columns, one for each week? Is a query doing a PIVOT on that data to generate the 52 columns? Is there *one* query populating the existing 2D array? Multiple queries?

Regardless, if you can refactor the code and put the query results in a DataTable, then you just bind that DataTable to the DataGridView as such:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable
```

Just make sure the DataGridView's AutoGenerateColumns property is set to True. And that's all there really is to it, to bind the data. However, you have to realize that simple binding such as this will display ALL fields in the DataTable. You'd have to manually set columns you don't want displayed to Visible = False in your code.

Conversely, you could create a Data Transfer Object (DTO), which is essentially just a class with only Properties. Then you'd instantiate one DTO object for each *row* in the query results, and add all those DTOs to a List(of T). Then, bind that List(Of T) to the DataGridView:

```
Dim myResults As List(Of PlanningDetailDTO) = myFunction.ReadTheData()
myDataGridView.DataSource = myResults
```

But I wouldn't really want to create a DTO class with 52+ fields in it. The advantage of the DataTable method is that it will create columns in the DataTable based on the query results.

Comment: The way the database is organized doesn't matter.  I convert raw data to business objects in my business tier (in between the UI and Data Access tiers).  I don't want to bind to raw data, I want to bind to a list of business objects.  The business objects class would define multiple lists to store the "rows" of data I want to display in the grid

Comment: See my my second edit on the OP.  I added some dummied up sample code to show what I want to do

Comment: One object translates to one row, not two or more rows. If you want to bind a DataGridView to business objects, it'll only be one row per object in the data source. And you'll also have to understand that child objects will not be displayed in full detail. I forget the exact behavior, but it might just add a column and the value will be the data type?

Comment: Do you have a source you could share that states "one object translates to one row, not two or more rows"?  I'm not being argumentative, I just want to be positive that what I am trying to do is not possible before giving up on the code refactor